# Oozie - how to get a Workflow action Type?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, workflow, oozie

I've recently started exploring Oozie and in order to implement an application logic need to get some information about an Action. I have managed to get statuses from CoordinatorAction this way:

```
public static final List<CoordinatorAction.Status> SUSPENDED_STATUS = Lists.newArrayList(CoordinatorAction.Status.SUSPENDED);
```

The question is how can I get a Type of an Action (Like KILL or END) that is shown in the UI?

As far as I have discovered CoordinatorAction interface does not provide such functionality.

[image]

Comment: Your screen shows Actions inside a **Workflow**...! Back to the basics: a Coordinator triggers executions of a specific Workflow. A Workflow contains Actions (and occasionally, links to sub-Workflows). An action is run as a YARN job _[shell, hive, etc]_ or as an internal Oozie routine _[decision, email, etc]_. But there is no such thing as a "Coordinator Action" -- except for some stupid naming convention in the API; "triggered Workflow executions" would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter thank you for the explanation. However I'm still looking for an advice on how to get an Action type from an Oozie client API.